# C# Comparing a reference and a value

Tags: c#, reference

I have trouble with this method when passing values to it.

Notice: The system using this function is from my perspective a black box and can therefore not be changed.

The problem is that passing identical values such as strings, bools, objects etc. to the method will say that they are not equal even though the values are identical. I assumed that it is because one is a reference while the other is a value and they therefore "are different".

```
    protected void SetData<T>(ref T field, T value)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("They are NOT equal");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("They are equal");
            }
        }
```

To test this assumption I made some different unit tests.

```
        public bool AreEqual<T>(ref T field, T value)
        {
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value);
        }
```

---

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsDirtyString()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = "Germany";
        var value = "United States";
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNotDirtyString()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = "Nepal";
        var value = "Nepal";
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsDirtyDouble()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = 11.2;
        var value = 12.3;
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNotDirtyDouble()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = 12.3;
        var value = 12.3;
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsDirtyInt()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = 12;
        var value = 15;
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNotDirtyInt()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = 12;
        var value = 12;
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsDirtyBool()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = true;
        var value = false;
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsNotDirtyBool()
    {
        var tc = new Program();
        var field = true;
        var value = true;
        var result = tc.AreEqual(ref field, value);
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
```

The result is that the unit tests all pass... as "expected"

So when I test, it works as intended, but when I connect to the rest of the system and debug so i can see the values of "field" and "value", it does not.

Has anybody tried something like this before?

Comment: why is `field` passed by reference at all? You don´t change the reference in your code.

Comment: And what are the values that you see when you debug?

Comment: You are comparing floating-point-numbers, whch you can´t really compare using a normal equals. Instead you should use some tolerance here. This way you can compare `12.3` with `12.3` in your unit-test, but when you have slightly differences between your values - e.g. `12.300000001` (which may come from a db-table) and `12.29999999993` (which comes from a different table).

Comment: What about Types, that cannot rely on the default equality comparer? Have a look at how the default equality comparer works. Especially for value types vs reference types. One of the arguments being passed by ref shouldn't make a difference. Also, check which equality will be checked on strings.

Comment: @GSerg Values I observe are mostly strings such as "Service International", "Unit No: 11982", "Europe"

but also objects with mostly null values and some properties mostly strings and ints

Comment: @HimBromBeer - It is some other job using this method, which I do not have access to, so that question i cannot answer

Comment: A custom type may not implement equality comparison. Then it will fall back to default behavior, which probably will be reference equality. Then objects with same content may be considered "not equal" because they are not _the same_ object. Similar for strings: They may be interned or not. So it is possible to have the same string (value) but 2 different references. If you then check reference equality, it will fail.

Comment: ... strings are even more tricky than that: "Hiho" and "hiho" - Would you consider them equal? In German "Strasse" and "Straße" are two valid ways to write the same word. Consider them equal? - What I am trying to get to is: You really need to deep dive into this and get straightened out what exactly you want to be considered equal on what types. Maybe you even need to use different critera for the _same type_ ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] exhibiting the problem, and not the code that shows that it is working the way you want it to work. I see nothing wrong with your code so I assume the problem is elsewhere, in code you haven't posted, so post a complete (but short) example that has this problem so that we can test it ourselves. You say the problem exists for strings, bools, objects. For your own types, you need to implement an interface for `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to be able to compare them, but for strings and bools this should work just fine.

Comment: Here's a dotnedfiddle that shows that your method works just fine for strings: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iWrUOW

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the equality comparer.

As you can see in this example even if equals, the output will be false:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza(1);
        Pizza pizza2 = new Pizza(1);
        bool equal = AreEqual(pizza1, pizza2);
        Console.WriteLine(equal);
    }

    public static bool AreEqual<T>(T field, T value)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value);
    }
}

public class Pizza
{
    public Pizza(int slices)
    {
        Slices = slices;
    }
    public int Slices { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

> False

---

This way it will work even with custom objects:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza(1);
        Pizza pizza2 = new Pizza(1);
        bool equal = AreEqual(pizza1, pizza2, new PizzaComparer());
        Console.WriteLine(equal);
    }

    public static bool AreEqual<T>(T field, T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
    {
        return equalityComparer.Equals(field, value);
    }
}

public class Pizza
{
    public Pizza(int slices)
    {
        Slices = slices;
    }
    public int Slices { get; set; }
}

public class PizzaComparer : IEqualityComparer<Pizza>
{
    public bool Equals(Pizza pizza1, Pizza pizza2)
    {
        return pizza1.Slices == pizza2.Slices;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Pizza pizza)
    {
        return pizza.Slices.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Output:

> True

Comment: He's saying in his question that this problem exists for types such as strings, bools, as well, which do have this interface implemented.